# How to use ANY and ALL operators in SQL to compute a value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given two tables: `Foo <----- Boo`

I would like to compute `Foo.status` and add it to the sql query based on the `Boo` values.

`select *, status from Foo;`

In python code, I do the following to generate the status of `Foo` but I would like to have it be part of the sql query.

How to use `ANY` and `ALL` operators directly in SQL to add a `status` column to the query?

```py
def get_status:
    boos = foo.boos.all()

    if all([i.value1 - i.value2 == 0 for i in boos]):
        return "status1"

    if all([i.value2 == 0 for i in boos]):
        return "status2"

    if any([i.value2 > 0 for i in boos]):
        return "status3"
```

Comment: I know too little of Python to understand what you are asking. With SQL we think in tables and their relations. So why not show a sample data table for foo, one for boo and one for the expected result? And sometimes it is way easier to understand things when they are less abstract. If you wouldn't talk of foo and boo, but of products and orders or of employees and departments or just anything real we can relate to, we might find it much easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have these tables

```
CREATE TABLE Foo(id int, ...);
CREATE TABLE Boo(id int, value1 int, value2 int, foo_id int,...);
```

You can compute status column first by CTE and join it with `Foo`.

```
WITH BooStatus as (
  SELECT b.foo_id, 
         CASE WHEN bool_and(b.value1 - b.value2 = 0) THEN 'status1'  
            WHEN bool_and(b.value2 = 0) THEN 'status2'  
            WHEN bool_or(b.value2 > 0) THEN 'status3'  
            ELSE 'undefined' 
         END as status
  FROM Boo as b GROUP BY b.foo_id
)
SELECT f.*, bs.status 
FROM Foo as f, BooStatus as bs WHERE f.id = bs.foo_id;
```

Edit:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo(id int,.. );
CREATE TABLE FooBoo(foo_id int, boo_id int);
CREATE TABLE Boo(id int, value1 int, value2 int,..  );

WITH BooStatus as (
  SELECT fb.foo_id, 
         CASE WHEN bool_and(b.value1 - b.value2 = 0) THEN 'status1'  
            WHEN bool_and(b.value2 = 0) THEN 'status2'  
            WHEN bool_or(b.value2 > 0) THEN 'status3'  
            ELSE 'undefined' 
         END as status
  FROM Boo as b,  FooBoo as fb 
  WHERE b.id = fb.boo_id
  GROUP BY fb.foo_id
)
SELECT f.*, bs.status 
FROM Foo as f, BooStatus as bs WHERE f.id = bs.foo_id;
```

Note that many to many relationship changes the problem description, you may need left join something else completely

Comment: Thank you. That seems to work. However, I realized that there is not a direct FK between `Boo` and `Foo`. There is actually a table between the two: `Foo <--- Rel ---> Boo`. I thought I could extrapolate to make it work but I am having a hard time to add the join to make it work. Could you please help?

Comment: @Mike did it work?